# how to calc difference between two column with results

Tags: mysql, sql

Could i calc for each row column Profit ?

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Revenue, -- 33 + 34 + 456 + 52...etc = 5500 
    SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 1 AND m.optimized = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Costs,-- 33 + 4...etc = 339 
    5500 - 339 AS Profit -- I need to get this difference 
    FROM messages AS m
JOIN rates AS r ON (r.id = m.rate_id    )
    GROUP BY
            m.client_account_id,
            m.mcc,
            m.mnc
```

[image]

[image]

I want to get

```html
| Revenue | Costs | Profit
   5500      500     5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your query into a subquery, then subtract the results.

```
SELECT Revenue, Costs, Revenue - Costs AS Profit
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Revenue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 1 AND m.optimized = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Costs
    FROM YourTable) AS x
```

Joining your two tables, and showing the results grouped by account, it would be:

```
SELECT client_account_id, mmc, mnc, Revenue, Costs, Revenue - Costs AS Profit
FROM (
    SELECT
        m.client_account_id, m.mmc, m.mnc
        SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Revenue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 1 AND m.optimized = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Costs
    FROM messages AS m
    JOIN rates AS r ON r.id = m.rate_id
    GROUP BY m.client_account_id, m.mmc, m.mnc
) AS x
```

Comment: SELECT Revenue, Cos......FROM messages) AS x FROM messages AS m | 19:47:44 Kernel error: Error( 1064 ) 42000: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM messages AS m
    


       
    FROM messages AS m

Comment: You can't have two `FROM` clauses in the same query.

Comment: i updated more full query, but i need to use messages table/ What we could do with it?

Comment: Show some sample table contents and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: Your sample result is just one total for everything. Why does your query have `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Which table is which? I don't see a `rate` column in either table. It would be nicer if you posted plain text instead of images, so we can search and copy them. Or make a sqlfiddle with the sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put it in a sub query :

```
SELECT Revenue - Costs as Profit
FROM (
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Revenue,  
SUM(CASE WHEN m.billable = 1 AND m.optimized = 0 THEN r.rate ELSE 0 END) AS Costs
) as temp
```